# iOS Calendar App Time Zone List

Tags: ios, swift3, timezone

As you can see in the screen below, iOS Calendar app shows the list of available time zone in `City, Country` format.

[image]

I want to attain the same list. Where can I get this list?

Comment: Have you tried this `NSTimeZone.knownTimeZoneNames()` ?

Comment: Yes, I have. It does not show as the same format as above.

Comment: @HamDongKyun - take a look at a few of the "Related" links to the right... there are a couple already asking / discussing your question.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters May I know why you have deleted my answer?

Comment: Sorry, did not look well enough. Found a similar post for this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456645/get-the-similar-timezone-list-as-in-iphone-settings-app

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get a "City, County" format, but you can get a "City, Continent" format using this piece of code:

```
let timeZones = TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers.flatMap{ id->String? in
    let components = id.components(separatedBy: "/")
    guard components.count == 2, let continent = components.first, let city = components.last else {return nil}
    return "\(city), \(continent)"
}
```

Output will be:

> "Abidjan, Africa", "Accra, Africa", "Addis_Ababa, Africa", "Algiers, Africa", "Asmara, Africa", "Bamako, Africa", "Bangui, Africa", "Banjul, Africa"...

Comment: So basically, your answer is I can not get as what iOS calendar app is providing, right?

Comment: Yes, this is the only thing you can get.

Comment: Then how is iOS Calendar App getting that list, in all the locale? Does it have a separate datastore not opened to the foundation API?

Comment: Yes, most probably it is using a private API.

Answer (score 0):

`TimeZone` has a static function `knownTimeZoneIdentifiers` which returns an array of String identifiers. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timezone/2293621-knowntimezoneidentifiers)

Comment: I know that documentation, but that does not show as the timezone shown like iOS calendar app