# Time duration based city and country asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to find out the duration between two different time zone. Issue is, I have only city and country with two date time. 
I am thinking, If I will able to get the time zone based on City and country then I will able to subtract the duration.

Supposed I am listing flight result page with departure date time and arrival date time.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/7977736/284240

Comment: You can check that SO question that refers to the same   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901/web-service-current-time-zone-for-a-city


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901/web-service-current-time-zone-for-a-city