# Get the default timezone for a country (via CultureInfo)

Tags: c#, timezone, country

Is there a program or a table that provides the default timezone for every country?

Yes, the US, Canada, & Russia have multiple timezones. (I think every other country has just one.) But it's better to start on the most likely if a country is known rather than just provide a list starting at GMT.

Preferably in C# but I'll take it in anything and convert to C#.

Comment: China. India. Iran. Brazil....

Comment: What is a "default timezone"??? The zone in with the capital of a country?

Comment: And Australia with at least three timezones, and some states, but not all, have daylight saving time, and Indiana in the US which uses at least two time zones.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @Andrew, fun fact: China has indeed only one timezone. Crazy, if you think about the size of that country. But Mongolia has two, that should balance it ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber - China, India, & Iran all have a single timezone.

Comment: @elgonzo - I think the capital would be best. But any reasonable one in the country would be fine.

Comment: @MikeW I'm not asking for an opinion on the best library that solves this. I'm just asking if such a solution exists at all.

Comment: @DavidThielen Do they really? I had no idea. I do know Brazil has multiple, though. (3, I think...)

Comment: @AndrewBarber That's why I think this would be a good thing to have. For most countries there is one. And for the remainder, most of the population is in just one of the several zones.

Comment: Also, I know France, Australia, Denmark, and the UK also have multiple. In fact, I think France has the most of any.

Comment: @David, maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977736/get-timezone-by-country-and-region . If not, perhaps you can stea..., erm... copy the table from Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zones_by_country) and make yourself a text/excel/csv/json/whatever file with the data.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977736/get-timezone-by-country-and-region). Not duplicate because you've imagined the concept of a "default" timezone, but the answer may help.

Comment: [Here's info from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zones_by_country) And also, I don't even know what a "Default timezone" would be. I don't think you are correct about people being centered in one timezone.

Comment: @Andrew: Since Greenland is basically an autonomous country (they are still member of the so-called "Kingdom of Denmark", though), Denmark has only one timezone (UTC+01:00)

Comment: @elgonzo OK, so Greenland has 4, then ;)

Comment: @Andrew: Greenland has 4? I thought they have 3. But yes, Greenland has indeed 4 timezones... I think the Chinese are jealous about Greenland...

Comment: @AndrewBarber for the U.S. & Russia no it's not one timezone for most people, although the East Coast may have close to half for the U.S. But for the rest I think yes. East Coast for Australia, Ontario for Canada, etc. ps I love the Brazil time that's for "a couple of islands."

Comment: This definitely made for a fun discussion

Comment: France? UK? Indonesia? Mexico? Spain? Portugal? And look at the split in time you would have between about half each of the US; Eastern and Pacific.

Comment: Antarctica has all timezones. Yay! Wait... that's no country...

Comment: @AndrewBarber France has one zone for France itself. UK has one for the British Isles. Spain & Portugal again one timezone for the main country. Indonesia & Mexico you would have to pick a default but Mexico's default is easy. Indonesia you do have a large population in two of them. But again, starting on either has the correct for half and it's one away in the drop-down list for the other half.

Comment: Speaking to myself: No, Antarctica does not have all timezones. But the penguins don't care anyway...

Comment: @MikeW: then daylight savings itself does not apply to all states, which complicates things even more...

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy That's what I meant to say, but it didn't quite come out right

Comment: @DavidThielen I agree this has been an interesting convo about the topic! :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As identified in the comments of the question, you aren't going to be able to get a single time zone for each country.  There are just too many cases of countries that have multiple time zones.

What you *can* do is filter the list of standard [IANA/Olson time zones](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) down to those available within a specific country.

One way to do this in C# is with [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org):

```
IEnumerable<string> zoneIds = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.ZoneLocations
    .Where(x => x.CountryCode == countryCode)
    .Select(x => x.ZoneId);
```

Pass a two-digit ISO-3166 country code, such as `"AU"` for Australia.  The results are:

```
"Australia/Lord_Howe",
"Australia/Hobart",
"Australia/Currie",
"Australia/Melbourne",
"Australia/Sydney",
"Australia/Broken_Hill",
"Australia/Brisbane",
"Australia/Lindeman",
"Australia/Adelaide",
"Australia/Darwin",
"Australia/Perth",
"Australia/Eucla"
```

And if for some reason you'd like Windows time zone identifiers that you can use with the `TimeZoneInfo` object, Noda Time can map those too:

```
var source = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default;
IEnumerable<string> windowsZoneIds = source.ZoneLocations
    .Where(x => x.CountryCode == countryCode)
    .Select(tz => source.WindowsMapping.MapZones
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.TzdbIds.Contains(
                             source.CanonicalIdMap.First(y => y.Value == tz.ZoneId).Key)))
    .Where(x => x != null)
    .Select(x => x.WindowsId)
    .Distinct()
```

Again, called with `"AU"` for Australia returns:

```
"Tasmania Standard Time",
"AUS Eastern Standard Time",
"Cen. Australia Standard Time",
"E. Australia Standard Time",
"AUS Central Standard Time",
"W. Australia Standard Time"
```

If you're wondering about how reliable this data is, the country to tzid mapping is part of the IANA time zone database itself, in the [zone.tab](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/zone.tab) file.  The IANA to Windows mapping data comes from the [Unicode CLDR supplemental data](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/zone_tzid.html).  It doesn't get any closer to "official" than that.

Comment: Could you try the same for `FO` country code?  (`Faroi Islands`) I can find the code in file (`zone.tab`) but in `C#` I am getting no results for this code..

Comment: Try the edit I just made.  I hadn't taken into account the IDs in the windows mapping are not always the TZDB canonical ones.

Comment: For windows time zone, it does not work for all cases, for example HR.

Comment: This produces redundant time zones.  For example, the United States only has 3-4 time zones but this returns 29 time zones, many of which are the same time zone!

Comment: Hello I found that the code doesn't work for country with code "AX" so here id my take on your solution: IEnumerable<TzdbZoneLocation> ZoneIds = source.ZoneLocations.Where(key => key.CountryCode == countryCode);
IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> WindowsZoneIDs = source.TzdbToWindowsIds;
List<string> Timezones = new();
foreach (var timezone in ZoneIds)
{
    if (WindowsZoneIDs.ContainsKey(timezone.ZoneId))
        Timezones.Add(WindowsZoneIDs[timezone.ZoneId]);
}

var TimezonesDistinct = Timezones.Distinct();

Comment: Is there a way to do this by specifying a CountryCode as well as an additional region identifier? For example in the US, if we just use "US", it will return all timezones, but if I do "US" and "NY", it will return America/New_York?

Comment: @RajeshPatel - No, because there are several states in the USA that observe more than one time zone.

Answer (score 4):

May not be exactly what you are looking for, but try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx

To get a specific time zone:

```
TimeZoneInfo tZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. Australia Standard Time");
```

To see the available zones:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> zones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();

foreach (TimeZoneInfo zone in zones)
{
     Console.WriteLine(zone.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to get CountryCode -> TimeZoneInfo mapping i used answer from Matt (2nd code snippet), but it didn't work for many cases. Found simpler and more reliable solution (using same Noda Time):  TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.WindowsMapping.MapZones basically has all the data.

Code sample:

```
Dictionary<string, TimeZoneInfo> GetIsoToTimeZoneMapping()
{
    var source = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default;

    return source.WindowsMapping.MapZones
        .GroupBy(z => z.Territory)
        .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => GetTimeZone(source, grp));
}

 TimeZoneInfo GetTimeZone(TzdbDateTimeZoneSource source, IEnumerable<MapZone> territoryLocations)
{
    var result = territoryLocations
        .Select(l => l.WindowsId)
        .Select(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById)
        //pick timezone with the minimum offset
        .Aggregate((tz1, tz2) => tz1.BaseUtcOffset < tz2.BaseUtcOffset ? tz1 : tz2);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Latest Windows versions contain file `%WINDIR%\Globalization\Time Zone\timezoneMapping.xml` which maps Olson to Windows time zone, you can query it as regular `XML`. I don't know but maybe `C#` already has a class which works with it.

Comment: Nice way to implement this can be found here https://codeofmatt.com/2014/04/07/working-with-time-zone-names-in-net/

Answer (score 1):

Some countries have more as one timezone for example russia.

In my solution i use [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org) if you have a longitude information available i select the best timezone for this country.

```cs
var countryName = "Russia";
var longitude = 40.332206;

var zones = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.ZoneLocations.Where(x => x.CountryName == countryName).AsQueryable();
if (!double.IsNaN(longitude))
{
    zones = zones.OrderBy(o => this.Distance(o.Latitude, longitude, o.Latitude, o.Longitude, DistanceUnit.Kilometer));
}
var bestZone = zones.FirstOrDefault();
var dateTimeZone = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.ForId(bestZone.ZoneId);

var newTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(dateTimeZone.MaxOffset.Seconds);
```

**Calculate distance of geo coordinates**

```cs
public enum DistanceUnit { StatuteMile, Kilometer, NauticalMile };

private double Distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, DistanceUnit unit)
{
    double rlat1 = Math.PI * lat1 / 180;
    double rlat2 = Math.PI * lat2 / 180;
    double theta = lon1 - lon2;
    double rtheta = Math.PI * theta / 180;
    double dist =
        Math.Sin(rlat1) * Math.Sin(rlat2) + Math.Cos(rlat1) *
        Math.Cos(rlat2) * Math.Cos(rtheta);
    dist = Math.Acos(dist);
    dist = dist * 180 / Math.PI;
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;

    switch (unit)
    {
        case DistanceUnit.Kilometer:
            return dist * 1.609344;
        case DistanceUnit.NauticalMile:
            return dist * 0.8684;
        default:
        case DistanceUnit.StatuteMile: //Miles
            return dist;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the per-country default timezones that Microsoft uses for Windows when a user first logs in. They list them at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones.

I also created a script which parses that table out into a JSON file at https://github.com/rahulgi/default-timezones.