# Get current UTC date in c# based on country code

Tags: c#, utc

How can I retrieve the current date with time in

> UTC format based on country code ?

For example, Afghanistan has ISO (country code) `AF`.

How to I pass this parameter `AF` in `DateTime.UtcNow` ?

Comment: Isn't UTC everywhere same irrespective of the location you are at that moment?

Comment: The current *UTC* date doesn't vary based on location.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert UTC/GMT time to local time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179940/convert-utc-gmt-time-to-local-time)

Comment: `U` in UTC stands for Universal. meaning it is same for all timezones.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the default timezone for a country (via CultureInfo)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695439/get-the-default-timezone-for-a-country-via-cultureinfo)

Comment: No, I want a method where I can pass the country code, and get the current datestamp.

Comment: DateTime.UtcNow will return the same result all over the world when calling at the same time and it is perfect to be used as a timestamp

Comment: There are countries with multiple timezones. What you're asking for is impossible. Read [ask], explain what problem you're trying to solve and show your research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UTC stands for Universal Time Co-ordinated. The whole point of it is that it is *always* the same, regardless of time zone or country. At the moment, in Britain the local time is 9:01 am as I type this, but the time in UTC is 8:01.

See https://www.timeanddate.com/time/aboututc.html

You are better off storing all timestamps in UTC and then converting them to local time for display.

So, to answer your question, you can't do it. Country and timezone are meaningless to UTC.

Hope this helps,

Adam.

Comment: To give you sense of scale, when this was written, Local time in India was 13:31 while the time in UTC was still 8:01. (That's because India is 5.30 hrs ahead of UTC, while ATM Britain is 1 hr ahead of UTC)

Answer (score 2):

As the answer above states, UTC is the timezone, it is not specific to any country.  Indeed even in the UK where the line intersects, only half the year is the same value as UTC, the rest is British Summer Time.

But if your question is how to turn Afghanistan time into UTC but you are not currently set to that timezone then

```
// you can get all the timezones your system supports using TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()
var afghanTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Afghanistan Standard Time");
var utcTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1), afghanTimeZone);
```

Time Zones do not match one for one with countries, and even inside a country there can be many more than one, so country code alone will not cut it.

Comment: Try not to use "positional" language to refer to other answers on SO. Due to voting, acceptance, randomization, and the ability for people to manually apply sorting, there's no guarantee that people in the future will be able to determine which answer is "the answer above" - instead I'd recommend *either* using the other answerer's username, *linking* to the other answer or both - e.g. [Adam's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43974262/15498)