# how match Timezone data of table according to GeoTime zone in .Net

Tags: c#

According to my table I have a column like Timezone standard name in which data as Like "Indian standard time", now I want to match this name by using Geo Time Zone package so how it can be done?  while Geo time Zone Package return only time zone like "Europe/London"...
eg:-

```
string tz = TimeZoneLookup.GetTimeZone(52.3702157, 4.8951679).Result
SELECT TimeZoneId FROM TimeZone WHERE NodaTimeZone LIKE '" + tz + "' OR GoogleTimeZoneName LIKE '" +  + "' ";
```

Actually I want Timezone name as googleTimeZoneName by GeoTimeZonePackage, now I got the output from Geotimezone package as same as TimeZoneId of google.

Comment: Not clear what you want to do, but you may want to check `TimeZoneInfo` class.

Comment: actually i got time zone name "Europe/London" after passing lat/lng in the timezonelookup.gettimezonezone(lat,lng).Result of Geotimezone nuget package after getting this result i want to compare this data from my table. and i want standard time as well.

Comment: actually i m not able to understand in Geotimezone what is purpose of alternativeresult

Comment: You can **edit** your question to include more information.

Comment: yes now you got

Comment: yes i want google timezoneName from C# because by this only i can compare and get desirable result. if it is possible please explain ASAP

Comment: now i want only standard name only daylight saving time doesn't matter at now

Answer (score 0):

By using [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/), you are able to get the corresponding windows timezone id. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19697827/926460) please.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using NodaTime.TimeZones;

namespace CodeTesting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string zoneName = "Europe/London";

            var tz = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.WindowsMapping.MapZones.FirstOrDefault(o => o.TzdbIds.Contains(zoneName)).WindowsId;

            Console.WriteLine(tz);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```