# Is there functionality to convert from UTC time to local time using country name?

Tags: c#, datetime, country

I have searched the method here but there is no case for me.

Is there functionality to convert from UTC time to local time using country name from excel ?

Example :

```
string CurrtTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

I would like to create a variable for localtime which receive value ( country name ) from Excel. How to do ?

string localtimenow = ____________.(CurrtTime).(Thailand)
string localtimenow2 = ____________.(CurrtTime).(Australia)

Expected results.

UTC TIME => yyyy-MM-dd 08:18:xx

BKK TIME => yyyy-MM-dd 15:18:xx

SYD TIME => yyyy-MM-dd 18:18:xx

Comment: No because it doesn't make sense. A country can have many timezones. You need to provide the *timezone name*

Comment: You have to get list of standard timezone for each country.

Comment: Check the duplicate. One answer shows how to [convert a UTC time to the machine's local time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/963812/134204). Another answer shows how to [use the Windows timezone name to convert UTC to any timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/455965/134204).

Comment: Get the timezone for the country. Refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695439/get-the-default-timezone-for-a-country-via-cultureinfo#19697827 & convert the UTC time to specific timezone of the country.

Comment: Australia has about 5 timezones

Comment: Thank you all. :)